# MySQL LOCK TABLES Alternatives (used in stored procedure)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Does somebody know a way to LOCK tables while a stored procedure is being executed?

My procedure is a simple aggregation process which loads data into other table. when it's done, it should update all selected rows as `aggregated` on the original table.

it seems essential to me to lock the original table during the procedure so i can avoid a situation in which  during the process new rows will be inserted the first table, but at the end of the process they still will be count as `aggregated` (as this update part applies for the whole table).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need locks.

If your database is an Innodb, use transactions.

With Myisam tables that don't support transactions, you could use your aggregation field with three values : not aggregated, aggregating, aggregated.

1. Your stored procedure will mark all rows selected as aggregating
2. Copy the marked rows to the new table
3. On completion update the row as aggregated
4. Reset the value if an error occurs.

Comment: could you please explain how would you implement the transactions in that case? i'm thinking of: start transaction > select > insert (aggregate) > update > commit. am i right?